# Trying to Use mediaelement.js alongside infinite-scroll plugin for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js, infinite-scroll

I'm using Paul Irish's Infinite-Scroll plugin with Wordpress, and I'm also trying to use John Dyer's mediaelement.js plugin with it. Works great on the individual posts, and, oddly enough, no problems on iPhone, but when viewing in Firefox, the audio defaults to a placeholder image of the player, that when you click on it, then turns to an "X" like i'm missing a flashplayer plugin or something. Like I said, I don't have the issue on the individual post pages, just on the index, so I know Firefox can handle the files properly.

I'm sure this has to do with needing to add some javascript in the settings of inifinite scroll to re-initialize mediaelement.js for each new page that is brought in, but I'm at a loss as to what I should add. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

John Dyer was awesome enough to answer this one for me.

```
$('video').mediaelementplayer()
```